# how do i run same python script for different inputs at different time in linux

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I have one python script which works for one input at a time. I have a list of inputs and I want this python script to run for different inputs independently in Linux.

Suppose this is my script:

```
script.py with input "name1", 
list of inputs = ["name1", "name2"]
```

Using for loop inside the script does not satisfy my requirement.
Is this possible using subprocess? or a for loop in another python file? If yes, then how?
I tried running this script.py using another python file with code:

```
from subprocess import call

for i in range(len(list_inputs)): ???

   call(["python", "script.py"])
```

but how do I give input to my script.py, also I do not want to give input by typing on terminal

Please suggest how do I do that?

Comment: IMHO, the simplest way is to pass parameters to the script: `for param in list_inputs: subprocess.run(['/path/to/python', '/path/to/script.py', param])`. Then you use `sys.argv` in script.py to get the parameter.

Comment: Thankyou so much...it helped a lot. This is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

You can run functions wtih multiprocessing in python with appropriate inputs. Like passing function arguments. But keep that in mind, you cannot pass global variables to subprocesses due to their nature(they dont share memory with parent-child processes). You can find an example usage below:

```
# Your desired function
def example_func(a, b, c):
    while True:
        print a
        print b
        print c

# Creating the child process
child_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=example_func, args=(a, b, c))

# Starting child process
child_process.start()
```

Comment: Thanks...but i have to run a python file, not just a function

Comment: You can define a runner function for your python file and import it accordingly to run it.